# Why footnotes appear out of order with bigfoot?

Tags: bigfoot

Why footnotes appear out of order at the bottom of page? How to make them appear in order at bottom of page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]
\begin{document}
\footnoteA{This should appear first at the bottom of page}
\footnote{This should appear second at the bottom of page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using two footnote apparatus (default and A)?

Comment: Because I need them and this just an example to demonstrate the issue I am having.

Comment: well the point of two apparatus is that the footnotes from the default is first than the next.

Comment: How can I make them apear in order at the bottom of page?

Comment: if you want the order to be maintained they should be in the same class, either both default or both A, _not_ maintaining the order between classes is the main point of having different classes.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the bigfoot package. Have a look into the manual, you'll get it (probably) by typing `texdoc bigfoot` on the command line. The manual has 60 pages and only two explain how to use the package. All the rest consists of the documentation of the 1600 lines of code of the package. To change something inside this machinery will be difficult. So unfortunately you are probably asking something non trivial.

And your question isn't really clear. Do you want to change the sequence of the footnotes only on the first page or for the whole document? So you need to elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Why can't you write your first footnote as a »normal« footnote? Or maybe have three types of footnotes and the default one only for such footnotes that have to be the first ones?!